# RestartSource.withBackoff never ends

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I´m trying to create Http client with Akka with a retry strategy where I want a max retries and then return the error. Having this code

```
private def makeRequest[T](system: ActorSystem,
                             host: String,
                             unmarshallFunc: ResponseEntity => Future[Either[ServiceNowAccessException, T]]): Future[Either[ServiceNowAccessException, T]] = {

    implicit val mat: Materializer =  Materializer(system)

    RestartSource.withBackoff(
      minBackoff = 10 seconds,
      maxBackoff = 10 seconds,
      randomFactor = 0.2,
      maxRestarts = 2
    ) { () =>
      Source.future(Http()(system).singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = host)))
        .mapAsync(parallelism = 1) {
          case HttpResponse(OK, _, entity, _) => unmarshallFunc(entity)
          case HttpResponse(InternalServerError, _, _, _) =>
            Future(Left(ServiceNowAccessException(InternalServerError.intValue)))
          case HttpResponse(statusCode, _, _, _) =>
            Future(Left(ServiceNowAccessException(statusCode.intValue())))
        }
    }.runWith(Sink.head)
  }
```

I´m unable to force the error after the `maxRestarts` and it keeps trying to forever to connect.

Any idea what's wrong with my code

Regards.

Comment: Is it restarting often? The time is important here. From https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/RestartSource$.html#withBackoff[T](settings:akka.stream.RestartSettings)(sourceFactory:()=>akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,_]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed] : `maxRestarts
the amount of restarts is capped to this amount within a time frame of minBackoff.`
It is also deprecated, did you consider replacing it with version that accepts RestartSettings?

Comment: Did you see this thread: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/restart-sources/2592/3  ?